# Recording system calls with arguments using perf

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, trace, perf

I want to record all of the system calls which are being called on a system. I know I can do this using various tracing tools but I want to do it using perf.

I have recorded syscalls using:

> perf record -e 'syscalls:sys_*' -a

I have looked at the output using both `perf record` and `perf script` but I am unable to interpret the output. I need the list of system calls along with their arguments being passed to them. Something like this:

- (syscall, arg1, arg2, ..)
- (syscall, arg1, arg2, ..)
- and so on

Can anyone help me get the desired output using perf?

Comment: You may have better luck using `ftrace`.

Answer (score 1):

Some improved output can be gained by using `perf trace -i perf.data` but you need a slightly different invocation to record.

```
# to record
$ perf record -e raw_syscalls:* /bin/true
# to report:
$ perf trace -i perf.data
```

The output is better than `perf script` gives you but can still be pretty inscrutable. `strace` figures more things out but it is harder to programmatically work with the output.

Answer (score -1):

perf is a profiler, why would it log arguments?

The tool you are looking for is systemtap.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using perf because I don't want to install any external tool I need something which would be available in standard linux distros (something built into kernel source tree, maybe?).

Comment: Perf does lots of things. It can do sampling profiling but it also has various tracing features.